# Reaction of chloride of 4th A group

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why CCl4 does not react with water,while SiCl4 do react,as both central atom are surrounded by 4 chlorine atom?

Answer (score 0):

Reaction of a compound with water is called hydrolysis.During hydrolysis, Si atoms of the chlorides make up of their empty d-orbitals in their valence shells to form coordinates bonds with water molecules.
However, C is in period 2 does not have d-orbitals in its valence shell to form coordinate bond with water and is not hydrolysed by water.

extra reading https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group4/chlorides.html

Comment: I would tend to believe steric effects before $d$ orbitals.